# New report from two tables with reportviewer doesnt have true result

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio-2013, reportviewer

I create a new view in SQL Server 2008 from two tables that have relation on a field. I want to create a report and do grouping on that common field.

For example:

```
table1: student(ID,first-name,last-name,phone,address,...)
table2: courses(ID,fk_ID,Course,....)
```

Now I want to have report that shows all data from both tables with grouping on ID from student table,  that must show courses information separated for every student. 
my query is:

```
SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT 
    dbo.tbl_student.ID,
    dbo.tbl_student.firstname, dbo.tbl_student.lastname,
    dbo.tbl_courses.Coursename, 
    dbo.tbl_Courses.CourseDate, dbo.tbl_courses.coursetype,  
FROM
    dbo.tbl_student LEFT OUTER JOIN
    dbo.tbl_courses ON dbo.tbl_student.ID = dbo.tbl_courses.fk_id 
ORDER BY 
    dbo.tbl_student.firstname DESC
```

But when I create a new report from this view, it shows just one record for every group. I spent 2 hours to solve the problem but I did not succeed.
please help me to create report from two or more tables.

**Now it shows one record duplicates for several times for every group**

Comment: What query did you try and what error did you get?

Comment: It  shows only one record for every student

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your query, so if it is not returning the results you expect, probably your data isn't what you think it is.

Comment: Please add some sample data and your expected result ;).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a query like this:

```
SELECT s.[ID], s.[first-name], s.[last-name], s.[phone], ...
       c.[ID], c.[Course], ...
FROM student s 
     LEFT OUTER JOIN
     courses c ON s.[ID] = c.[fk_ID]
```